# Getting value of a subclass of a subclass on Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Thanks to [Andreas Rejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282848/andreas-rejbrand) for helping me improve this question. 
I'm creating a program that has the featuring classes and subclasses:

```
TBall= class
private
public    
  procedure Hit;
end;

TBilliardBall = class(TBall)
private
  number:integer;
public    
  procedure ValidPot; virtual; abstract;
end;

TBilliardBallLow= class(TBilliardBall)
private
public
  procedure ValidPot();override;
end;

TBilliardBallHigh= class(TBilliardBall )
private
public
  procedure ValidPot();override;
end;
```

On the var section, I created one instance of the SubClasses BallLow and BallHigh for each ball group and was doing separate feature for each team and ball type:

```
Ball1 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball2 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball3 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball4 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball5 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball6 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball7 : TBilliardBallLow;
Ball9 : TBilliardBallHigh;
Ball10: TBilliardBallHigh;
Ball11: TBilliardBallHigh;
Ball12: TBilliardBallHigh;
Ball13: TBilliardBallHigh;
Ball14: TBilliardBallHigh;
Ball15: TBilliardBallHigh;
```

I was working on a method, that I concluded that It needs to receive one parameter for a ball, and can be the High numbers or Low numbers. If i create a function that receives a TBilliardBall, and try to send one of the instances i created, will it work?
I was thinking of something like that:

```
procedure Button1OnClick(Sender: TObject)
begin
TBall.Hit(Ball1);
end;

procedure TBall.Hit(BallHit: TBilliardBall);
begin
Ballhit.Validpot;
end;
```

I need to have the method `validPot` in my program, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Isn't a `TBilliardBall` a `TBall`?

Comment: Also, "I created one subclass for each ball". Probably you mean "I created one ball instance for each ball on the table; each ball is either a `TBilliardBallLow` or a `TBilliardBallHigh`." (Well, technically, in the `var` section you don't create objects. You only declare variables. In the code block, you can then create objects and assign their pointers to these variables.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks for the reminder, it's kinda difficult to translate my code to english

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand and yes, that is what I was trying to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
procedure TBall.Hit(BallHit: TBilliardBall);
begin
  BallHit.ValidPot;
end;
```

is a perfectly valid method, since `ValidPot` is a public method of `TBilliardBall`. But you *must not* pass an instance of `TBilliardBall` to this method, because that is an abstract class without an implementation of `ValidPot`. Instead, you *must* pass a `TBilliardBallLow` or a `TBilliardBallHigh` object. By declaring the `BallHit` parameter as a general `TBilliardBall`, you are free to pass a billiard ball of either of those types.

Also, in your example at least, this is a method of `TBall`. Hence, in the interface section, you must declare this method properly:

```
TBall = class
private
public    
  procedure Hit(BallHit: TBilliardBall);
end;
```

Now, there is a slight problem. When you declare the `TBall` class in the interface section, you haven't yet declared `TBilliardBall`, so it remains an undeclared type. And obviously you cannot simply reverse the order and declare `TBilliardBall` before `TBall`.

The solution is to use a [forward declaration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes):

```
TBilliardBall = class; // <-- a forward declaration

TBall = class
private
public    
  procedure Hit(BallHit: TBilliardBall);
end;
```

Comment: I need one of the two in my method: BilliardBallLow or BilliardBallHigh, that's why i was trying to find a solution for that, because two of them looks unecessary. Thanks for explaining it to me

Answer (score 2):

Why are you declaring `TBilliardBallLow` and `TBilliardBallHigh` subclasses in the first place? Wouldn't it be much easier if you include your `LowBall` or `HighBall` as property of your `TBilliardBall` class instead.

And since you already store ball number in your TBilliardBall class you can then easily calculate if particular ball is Low or High ball using simple math comparison. So your class `TBilliardBall` class would look something like this:

```
TBilliardBall = class(TBall)
private
  number:integer;
protected 
  function GetHigh: Boolean;
public    
  procedure ValidPot;
  property IsHigh: Boolean; read GetHigh;
end;

implementation

function TBilliardBall.GetHigh: Boolean;
begin
  if FNumber > 7 then result := True
  else Result := False;
end;
```

Comment: I'm doing an exercise that I need to create those subclasses with those specific names, that's the reason.

Comment: I'm treating the 8 ball separately of the rest of them, so `FNumber > 7` can result in some problems, because the 8 ball have some rules that doesn't apply to the rest of them, and I need to validate that in another procedure